# How to declare a snippet containing variables as a variable to avoid code duplication using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

The snippet `(Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1)` is called three times. The aim is to declare it as a variable to avoid code duplication.

```bash
Get-ChildItem "$env:ChocolateyInstall\lib\eclipse.*" -Recurse -Filter "eclipseInstall.zip.txt" | 
    ForEach-Object{ if (((Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1) -match "eclipse") -and (Test-Path -Path (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1))){Remove-Item -Recurse -Force (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1)}}
```

**Attempt**

```bash
$a = (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1)

Get-ChildItem "$env:ChocolateyInstall\lib\eclipse.*" -Recurse -Filter "eclipseInstall.zip.txt" | 
    ForEach-Object{ if (($a -match "eclipse") -and (Test-Path -Path (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1))){Write-Host "hello"}}
```

**Result**

```bash
PS C:\Windows\system32> . "C:\temp\powershelltest\test.ps1"
Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\temp\powershelltest\test.ps1:1 char:19
+ $a = (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1)
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentC
   ommand
```

Comment: It's not clear from this what you're actually trying to do. Can you edit the question and explain? The error comes because you're trying to access `$_` which doesn't exist as you've not created a pipeline yet.

Comment: @arco444 I am trying to avoid code duplication. The same snippet, i.e. `(Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1)` is called three times at the moment. The question has been updated.

Comment: OK, but _why_? What's the actual purpose of the script? You're assigning correctly, but what you're trying to assign is incorrect. i.e. using `$a = (..)` is fine, but you can't do a straight `Get-Content $_.Fullname` without first piping to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a snippet of code to a variable like this:

```
$a = { Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -First 1 }
```

Then execute the snippet at any time with `& $a` (you would need to pipe an object to it). I'm not sure this is necessary in your example though.